# Entity framework asp net MVC bug when date field is empty it overrides existing date during edit action

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, datetime, data-binding

I created scaffolded controller for CRUD project and there is a bug. When I Create new entity(record) for MySql DB it works as expected, one of those values is HiredDate. But when I go to Edit something for example FiredDate inside different view it overrides Previously created record for the HiredDate and sets it to 0001-01-01 .

Here is code for the **Model**:

```
        [Column("City", TypeName = "varchar(100)")]
        public string City { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Column("Department", TypeName = "varchar(100)")]
        public string Department { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Column("HiredDate", TypeName = "date")]
        [Display(Name = "Hired On")]
        public DateTime HiredDate { get; set; }

        [Column("FiredDate", TypeName = "date")]
        [Display(Name = "Fired On")]
        public DateTime? FiredDate { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Column("ModifiedDate", TypeName = "datetime")]
        [Display(Name = "Modified Date")]
        public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
```

And **Controller** code for *edit*:

```
   public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("ID,FirstName,LastName,Email,Phone,Age,City,Department,FiredDate")] Employee employee)
        {
            if (id != employee.ID)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    _context.Update(employee);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    if (!EmployeeExists(employee.ID))
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(employee);
        }
```

And **Controller** code for *create*:

```
   public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("FirstName,LastName,Email,Phone,Age,City,Department,HiredDate")] Employee employee)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(employee);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(employee);
        }
```

Result of the override looks something like this:
[image]

How can I fix it? I want HiredDate to stay unchanged(for example 2020-01-01) when I do Edit action and modify any other fields except HiredDate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind I found the problem, This BIND is really not user friendly, it forces developers to show all fields inside the view and if one is missing its going to override with null values the one thats missing.
The solution is inside Edit View Form. This Form should display all fields that your Model has.